# open other activity from view

Tags: android

How to open activity from view? I am develop a game if game is over I need to move user to main menu activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all. i got solution myself.

```
Activity activity=(Activity)this;
```

i passed this activity object to my view and then i have done

```
activity.finish();
```